# Hover /selected menu show background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some hover effect on background of `ul li`.

Image:

**HTML**

```
<div id="topnav">
        <ul class="nav clearfix">
            <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-25">
            <a href="http://localhost/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-45">
                <a href="http://localhost/">Menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-98">
                <a href="http://localhost/">Menu3</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-96">
                <a href="http://localhost/">Menu4</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-97">
                <a href="http://localhost/">Menu5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #topnav {
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 2%;
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        float: left;
        font-size: 8pt;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-top: 7% !important;
        opacity: 0.8;
        padding: 0;
        width: 60%;
    }
    #topnav ul {

        line-height: 1;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
         display: block;
    }
    #topnav ul li {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        margin:10px;
    }
    #topnav ul {
        line-height: 1;
        list-style: none outside none;
    }
```

Comment: Sir i just wants to show a white background only.. no color /font issue..

Comment: i have updated with some more css on hover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/kaGvs/1/

Comment: Just to clarify, excuse me ... you need the area "behind" the buttons turns white on hover?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/5/ ?

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen sir please make it ans.. i need to give you +1 and accept as ans.

Comment: @HopeFull .. hehe ok .. hope its what you needed ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: [jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/5](http://jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/5) ? :)

You can give the "a" tag a minus margin and border, which should cancel each other.

```
#topnav ul li a {
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom : 15px solid transparent;
    margin: -25px 0;
    display:block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#topnav ul a:hover, #topnav ul ul a:hover {
    color: #0A0A0A;
    background-color: #CBBBA1;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know with css3 you can not select the parent of an element (I may be wrong). With JQuery is rather easy `$("#topnav a:hover").parent()` this will select the li that contains the a:hover.

Hope i understood the question and this helps you.

JQuery Example of coloring the li in white, you will have to resize the li so this effect can be visible:

```
$(function(){
$("#topnav a").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#topnav a:hover").parent().css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $("#topnav a:hover").parent().css("background-color","#CBBBA1");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#topnav ul li:hover{
    background:white; 
}
#topnav ul li:hover a{
    background:#d8b038; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/10/)**

**Note:** *Alter the positions according to your UI. I have just given the hover effect.*

Comment: thnakx for you ans..
But i need Something like this: jsfiddle.net/kaGvs/5 and it is solved/